# How does the wife know she has rescued her husband’s killer?

Tags: plot-explanation, hunter-hunter

In the movie Hunter Hunter, the wife rescues a stranger, nursing him and feeding him before going out to look for her missing husband in the forest. Then she finds her husband’s dead body with a head wound.

She suddenly realises she has rescued her husband’s killer. How does she realise it? The only correlation between her husband’s murder and the stranger she rescued is perhaps the fact that she estimates her husband was killed roughly moments before she found this wounded stranger.

But this correlation is pretty weak.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: I haven't seen the movie myself, but from reading a synopsis, I gather it takes place in a remote wilderness. You say the husband apparently died from a head wound - did he have any other wounds?  Most animals wouldn't be able to reach a person's head without getting him on the ground first (and predators would likely try to eat his body after killing him) therefore there would be *other injuries,* not just a single head wound. Again, I haven't seen it, but I'm guessing the inury was clearly inflicted by another human, and there are none for miles, besides this stranger.

Comment: @Steve-O, yeah; still pretty thin. The head wound could have been caused by many other reasons. She held her husband into her arms and just like that, she knew the head wound came from another human.